# Undistorting night sky star motion (given that stars don't move)

Tags: statistics, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, least-squares

My ultimate goal: out of 500 night-sky photos, I'd like to distort 499 of them to the exact star position of the first one.  (Imagine a fancy motorized star-tracking rig, but done with math instead of motors)

But I don't know my camera's distortion, so is there a way to brute-force solve this?

What I've got to work with:

1. 500 2-second nighttime photos over a several hour range.
2. Perfectly stationary camera (normal field of view)
3. Extracted star locations as x,y pixel coordinates
4. Star correlation, for the ~15 brightest stars I know: frameTimeLocation(time, bright_star_number) = (x,y)
5. Exact time each of the 500 photos were taken
6. The knowledge that stars don't move relative to each other
7. The knowledge that stars are rotating around a fixed point (which may be outside the camera's FOV)
8. The assumption that the distortion of the camera is smooth

Assuming everything above, I could either

1. Solve [the camera distortion equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_(optics))
2. Solve [some general distortion field matrix thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6E2I.jpg)

The problem is that I'm not sure how to start with either.  I'm very much a programmer and not as much a mathematician, and eventually I need to end up with pixelValuesAcrossAllPhotosMappedToTime0(targetx, targety) = 500 pixels of data.

Comment: I would model this with three sets of unknowns: (1) the undistorted star positions $(x_s,y_s)$ in the first photo, (2) the distortion function $f$ of the camera, and (3) the homographies $h_p$ from the first photo to each other photo. Then you could solve a nonlinear least-squares problem to minimize the total error across all stars and all photos, $\sum_s \sum_p \|f(h_p(x_s,y_s)) - (\hat x_{s,p},\hat y_{s,p})\|^2$, where $(\hat x_{s,p},\hat y_{s,p})$ is the observed position of star $s$ in photo $p$.

Comment: Huh!  That seems to ignore 6, 7, and 8.  But maybe that is ok...  Any hints on how to get started with that approach?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. [Celestial cartography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_cartography) is very well developed. You don't need to take a photograph to know where the few thousand brightest stars are located in the sky.

Comment: @Somos I'm trying to emulate a fancy motorized mount for long exposures where the camera stays in perfect alignment with the night sky as the earth rotates - but all through math applied to short exposure photos from a fixed camera.

Comment: Actually I'm using 6 by assuming that the stars are fixed and the camera is rotating, which is just a change in perspective. And you can encode 8 in the way you model the camera distortion function. What I'm ignoring rather are 5 and 7. There are still a lot of details to fill in to make this a concrete method, which I'm afraid I don't have time for, sorry... I just gave some hints in the hope that you had some prior knowledge of numerical data fitting which you could apply to make it work.